# Fancybox onload - Not loading background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am trying to have a fancy box appear onload, it's working so far but it's not loading the greyed out background. AT the moment I have a hidden div and then I call it, so the div is appearing but not the other fancybox features.

Does anyone have any idea?

```
<div id="warning">
    <h3>Please use Internet Explorer</h3>
</div>

<!-- FancyBox for browser warning-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.fancybox("#warning");
        });
    </script>
```

So it's like this:
[image]

I want it like this:
[image]

Comment: The fancybox overlay uses a semi-transparent PNG file whose location is set in CSS. Have you checked that the path to that image is correct?

Comment: Yes, when I have the code that you click on a link and thent eh pop up box comes it works with the semi-transparent PNG, but when i have it open automatically it loses it.